# Two way communicating server/client architecture?

Tags: c#, wcf, sockets, architecture, client-server

I'm trying to figure out which client/server technology (i.e. which part of the .NET Framework) to use for our new application. We will be writing the app in C# using .NET 3.5 SP1.

It is going to consist of a central Service that will be running as a "server", and several client applications spread out on several machines. The client application is a trayapp application that is going to receive notifications from the server, and will also send some information back to the server. The communication will therefore be two-way, and it needs to be fast. The server will need to know which client to send the notifications to.

I've been thinking that I could use Sockets. I've also come across the TcpListener and TcpClient classes. Another alternative is to do something with WCF, but I'm not sure how to do fast two-way communication with it.

Comment: Have a look here http://realfiction.net/go/113

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing how much data you're planning to exchange, it's difficult to make a precise recommendation.  I use both WCF and TCP sockets to exchange data between my UI and my Windows service.  Here are the considerations I made.

I use WCF for what I refer to as aperiodic data exchange.  For example, when an event occurs in my Windows service, I communicate the event to the UI using WCF.  Specifically for this event-based mechanism, I would highly recommend Juval Lowy's [Publish-Subscribe Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx), which is available for free [here](http://www.idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=5&tabid=11#Operations).  I also use WCF to communicate configuration changes from the UI to the Windows service.  WCF is a perfect solution for this kind of data exchange for me.

When the user tells my Windows service to perform some action, a lot of data is sent from the Windows service to the UI.  For this, I use TCP sockets.  I know WCF has a streaming capability, and I strongly considered using it.  I just did not have time to get comfortable with it before I had to make a decision, so I went with what I knew.

While I wish I was using WCF across the board for symmetry, i.e., for aperiodic and streaming data, this hybrid approach has served me well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

WCF with NetTcp binding.

You should write a duplex service.

Comment: Could you go into more detail, advantages/disadvantages. High level overview of what WCF and NetTcp brings or why a duplex service should be used, etc.

Comment: @Ray: it's not really necessary. WCF should be used for all such work unless there's a real good reason not to; netTCPBinding is the obvious choice for .NET to .NET WCF communication; and a duplex service is the only way to do two-way communication with WCF.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid sockets if I were you since there is a lot to know about them. Just look at all [socket questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#+sockets) here at SO. It can be a nightmare if you do not know how to use them properly.

WCF will take care of all lower levels for you.